# Elastic search find difference in a field using range query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to find out how many KWH has been run between two given time. For now, I am having 2 queries to find out last and the first record between the time using asc and desc sorting and doing subtraction to get the KWH value between the time is there any other way to get the KWH without 2 queries

Range query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "createdtime": {
              "gte": "1566757800000",
              "lte": "1566844199000",
              "boost": 2.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "meter_id": 101
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size" : 1,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": { "createdtime" : {"order" : "desc"} }
}
```

another query is almost same except the order is asc

So both the 2 queries will return the record, and I am doing the subtractions in the result set to find out the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run **one query** only and use `top_hits` aggregation to extract the "first" and "last" value, but it won't calculate the difference. You'd still have to do it outside Elasticsearch.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "createdtime": {
                  "gte": "1566757800000",
                  "lte": "1566844199000",
                  "boost": 2.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "meter_id": 101
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "range": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "createddate": {
                        "gte": "2016-08-19T10:00:00",
                        "lte": "2016-08-23T10:00:00"
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{"createddate": {"order": "asc"}}],
                        "_source": {"includes": [ "kwh_value" ]},
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                },
                "max": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{"createddate": {"order": "desc"}}],
                        "_source": {"includes": [ "kwh_value" ]},
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very close how to use match query with this? I am a newbie to elasticsearch

Comment: Updated my answer @JothiKannan.